# App icon displays a black square.

Tags: ios

I am having my app icon be displayed as a black square instead of the intended image. 
[image]

I have placed all of my AppIcons into the folder, Im wondering what could be causing this.

Comment: What file format are you using? Did you have the correct dimensions in your asset?

Comment: I am using PNG. I believe I have the right dimensions since when I was dragging the icons into the AppIcon catalogue the icon dimensions where highlighted before I even dropped the image at that specific icon.

Comment: Did you clean **and** clear the target, removed the app and reinstalled it?

Comment: I did run clean a few times and remove from the iphone, and removed from simulator. Still the black image persists.

Comment: Try to clear or remove the DerivedData folder

Comment: Is that the folder that contains the images? Or is that the name of the folder? Im not sure if that will fix the problem though since I have deleted and made a new AppIcon folder several times now.

Comment: That's the name of the folder that contains compiled data etc., it's located at `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` by default but I highly recommend to change it to "relative to project" in the locations tab in settings, it often solves uploading issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57721/discussion-between-julian-and-them00s3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image needs to be an opaque PNG. No transparency or anything, as well as being the correct size.

If it already is that, try opening it in Preview and re-saving it as a PNG. That way OS X 'generated' it and it should be compatible. If that helps fix the issue, then your image editing program is saving in the wrong format...see info below.

Apple has this to say on generating PNGs:

> For all images and icons, the PNG format is recommended. You should avoid using interlaced PNGs.
>
> The standard bit depth for icons and images is 24 bits—that is, 8 bits each for red, green, and blue—plus an 8-bit alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen when the app is listed as a .png file, but the system is recognizing it as a .jpg or some other type ... find your icon in "finder" and open it with preview, go to the file menu select "export as" and make sure you choose PNG as the save format. Delete the old version in the application, delete the derived data, clean your project, and rebuild the application.